# Can I be mostly dependent on solar and batteries?

Tags: renewable-energy, energy-storage, solar, electricity

Plan A:

Ask your neighbors to give you permission to install solar panels on their roofs (ofcourse you can manipulate them into saying yes by giving them money once off )

So Ask your neighbors to give you permission to install solar panels on their roofs, make it clear to them that the solar will only be producing power for your house ,and that you only require land to pu the solar panels on ,and since a room is usually unused you can place them there.

These solar panels will be used to recharge your batteries for later use and will also be helpful during the day when you're cooking or just changing up your devices.

(Fun fact ,you cannot trust a human being to honor your contract or agreement, especially in areas that are likely to have electricity related problems like loadshedding or load reduction or blackouts or just plain high electricity prices per kWh, thus they could just betray you when they see how helpful your plan is to your standard of living,  i.e less electricity bills to pay ,so they'll be like ,  "oh he'll no why would I allow 'insert-gender-pronoun-here' to have electricity when I don't, I should just cut these wires off or just modify this so that I will also have electricity " -they will tend to forget the deal  or agreement or contract that you had so tread lightly.

Plan B:

buy plots of land nearby where you'll build rooms for rent and install solar panels at an acceptable elevation (on the roof of the rooms ) and make sure there's an automatic cleaning system available for the solar panels (as you won't be doing this manually)

Then connect batteries to the solar panels  so they can recharge during the day.

Then you can send an automated robot to go collect those batteries and connect them to your house (note that this is difficult to program in a robot) ,repeat this process for the other plots pf land too. And keep rotating the batteries.

Remember that it will be 100% your responsibility to protect your solar hardware (check property protection laws or by-laws in your area or country)

These solar panels will charge batteries for your benefit, not the benefit of the people that will be renting since solar will not be part of the deal. (So they will but their own electricity and own water and you will be getting money from them every month and you'll also be rotating in and out the batteries and using them)

(Note:

- I'll use my country's electricity as back up
- and I'll use propane and a propane inverter generator as last resort.
  )

So which plan is the best (like which plan is more likely to work ) ?

Plan A (depending on neighbors)
Or
Plan B (buying your own plot of land nearby)

Comment: This isn't an engineering question, it's a social or political one. How do you compensate your neighbors? What happens when a neighbor says yes, you install & then they say no? With either plan, if a someone damages the installation for whatever reason, what do you do? Technically, the key is to get enough area cover with solar cells. If land, could that land be used for something else, such as farming or buildings? If roofs, do you have enough roof space orientated in the right direction?

Comment: If you haven't invented hyper competent robots, you can compromise by running a cable from the solar farms to your home.....

Comment: Mankind survived without depending on electricity for a long time. Historical evidence thus suggests that neither solar panels not batteries are necessary for survival. Whether you can be "dependent" on them or not is a matter of your wants.

Answer (score 1):

Neither plan is necessary. In my locale many people are full solar as they have no access to mains lines. It's more about the size of your battery bank than the number of panels. One chap has just two panels, but around 50 batteries.

Then you buy your appliances with solar in mind. Many appliances are available for solar set ups.

Answer (score 1):

My son has a tiny house, no grid connection.

2 panels, 2 gel batteries, 24V system, 500W inverter to run solar water heating, 2kW inverter for occasional use.

Care required in winter as sun is lower in sky ie power is less.

All the power in can be calculated - angle of sun in sky etc

You need to decide your power requirements: my son is minimalist and NEVER leaves anything on...
However, if you plan on running a 20kW AC unit 24/7/365 you many need to purchase a solar farm...

But it is all down to planning and understanding the energy use.